# Expresión regular para eliminación de comentarios de código

Tags: java, regex

Estoy tratando de hacer una expresión regular que elimine comentarios del estilo `//` y `/**/`, de momento utilizaba una sacada de [este sitio](http://blog.ostermiller.org/find-comment):

```
(/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/)|(//.*)
```

El problema estaba cuando el comentario estaba en forma de string literal (**tanto con comillas simples como dobles**), por ej.:

```
var a = "//Holaaa";
```

Por lo que traté de usar `lookbehind` y `lookahead` juntos para escapar ambas comillas y me quedó así:

```
(?<!\"|\')((/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/)|(//.*))(?!\"|\')
```

El problema de esto es que para casos como los siguientes no funciona:

```
var ar = "asasasas /*dsdsdsd*/ "
var ar = "asaasas //dsdsdsd"
var ar = "asasasas /*dsdsdsd*/ dsadasdsda"
var ar = "asaasas //dsdsdsd asdsadsadsad"
```

Traté cambiando `(?<!\"|\')` por `(?<!\"|\'.*)` y `(?!\"|\')` por `(?!.*\"|\')`, pero tampoco resultó.

¿Que me estoy perdiendo?

**Nota:** la idea es utilizarla en Java, pero no necesariamente la respuesta tiene que ser en su estandar, con que sepa la expresión más tarde puedo adapartarla por mi cuenta.

Comment: El regex es en Java, pero ¿el código al que estás buscando eliminarle los comentarios también es Java?

Comment: Los comentarios que estoy tratando de eliminar son tanto de java, como C, C++, JavaScript y todos los que utilicen // o /**/

Comment: Entonces, no sólo tiene que considerar las comillas dobles, sino también comillas simples, heredoc, nowdoc, expresiones regulares... la lista se va alargando... puedo contestarte a cada caso, pero deberías listarlos en la pregunta...  a menos que las comillas dobles sean la única excepción que te interese (recomendaría que dijeras eso en la pregunta, y luego trabajaras sobre la respuesta para agregar el resto de las excepciones)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la observación. Ahí edité la pregunta aclarando que solo me interesa escapar las comillas simples y dobles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problema

Honestamente, el regex que sacaste de esa página es muy malo, no sólo en lo que deja sin considerar, sino también en términos de eficiencia. Tu intento de arreglarlo con aserciones (*lookahead*/*lookbehind*) es bueno, pero es una estrategia que no tiene buenos resultados. La explicación del por qué no va a funcionar es demasiado extensa, pero se podría resumir en que algo como `(?<!"|')` sólo verifica 1 caracter hacia atrás de la posición actual y, por más que pudiésemos hacerlo de largo variable (-no, no se puede), no podrías determinar si la comilla previa está abriendo o cerrando un comentario. En resumen: estrategia equivocada (en la que todos hemos caído).

### Solución

Para este tipo de casos, donde es relevante toda la sintaxis previa a la posición en la que se busca coincidir, la forma de llegar a ese punto es consumiendo cada parte del texto, mientras se valida cada estructura.

El regex, debería estar anclado al principio del texto, o el final del reemplazo anterior (`\G`), e ir coincidiendo el texto donde un comentario no tiene significado, hasta encontrar el comentario. A grandes rasgos sería reemplazar

```
\G  ([lo que no es comentario]*)  comentario
```

donde se captura todo el texto previo y se incluye en al reemplazar por

```
$1
```

#### Expresión regular

Ahora bien, encontrar todo *lo que no es comentario*, implica coincidir con todos los caracteres **excepto los que tienen un significado especial**, e ir agregando reglas para que coincida con cada una de esas excepciones (una `\` que escapa a un caracter, texto entre comillas, etc).

Como forma de simplificar la explicación, comenté el regex con el objetivo de cada estructura:

```
\G                                  # Anclar a \A o fin de coincidencia previa
(                                   # GRUPO 1: capturar todo lo que no es comentario en $1:
  [^"'/\\]*                         #   caracteres sin significado especial
  (?:                               #   estructuras especiales:
    (?: \\.                         #       a. barra escapando caracter
      | /(?![*/])                   #       b. una / que no está seguida de / o *
      | "[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"    #       c. texto entre comillas dobles
      | '[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'    #       d. texo entre comillas simples
    )                               #
    [^"'/\\]*                       #     seguido de más caracteres sin significado
  )*+                               #   (estructuras especiales repetidas 0 a inf)
)                                   # fin de Grupo 1

(?:                                 # COMENTARIOS (no está dentro de $1)
   //.*                             #   a. // hasta el final de la linea
|  /\*[^*]*(?:\*(?!/)[^*]*)*\*/     #   b. /* hasta el siguiente */
)
```

O en una línea sin comentarios:

```
\G([^"'/\\]*(?:(?:\\.|/(?![*/])|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')[^"'/\\]*)*+)(?://.*|/\*[^*]*(?:\*(?!/)[^*]*)*\*/)
```

Con barras y comillas escapadas para Java:

```java
final String regex = "\\G([^\"'/\\\\]*(?:(?:\\\\.|/(?![*/])|\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\"|'[^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^'\\\\]*)*')[^\"'/\\\\]*)*+)(?://.*|/\\*[^*]*(?:\\*(?!/)[^*]*)*\\*/)";
```

**Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/wDg8LJ/1/

---

#### Código en Java

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```java
final String regex = 
       "\\G"                                         // Anclar a \\A o fin de coincidencia previa
     + "("                                           // GRUPO 1: capturar todo lo que no es comentario en $1:
     + "  [^\"'/\\\\]*"                              //   caracteres sin significado especial
     + "  (?:"                                       //   estructuras especiales:
     + "    (?: \\\\."                               //       a. barra escapando caracter
     + "      | /(?![*/])"                           //       b. una / que no está seguida de / o *
     + "      | \"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\""  //       c. texto entre comillas dobles
     + "      | '[^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^'\\\\]*)*'"      //       d. texo entre comillas simples
     + "    )"                                       //
     + "    [^\"'/\\\\]*"                            //     seguido de más caracteres sin significado
     + "  )*+"                                       //   (estructuras especiales repetidas 0 a inf)
     + ")"                                           // fin de Grupo 1
     + "(?:"                                         // COMENTARIOS (no está dentro de $1)
     + "   //.*"                                     //   a. // hasta el final de la linea
     + "|  /\\*[^*]*(?:\\*(?!/)[^*]*)*\\*/"          //   b. /* hasta el siguiente */
     + ")";

final String texto = 
       "var ar1 = \"asasasas /*dsdsdsd*/ \"\n"
     + "var ar2 = \"asaasas //dsdsdsd\"\n"
     + "var ar3 // = \"asaasas //dsdsdsd asdsadsadsad\"\n"
     + "/*var ar4*/ = \"asasasas /*dsdsdsd*/ dsadasdsda\" /*\n"
     + "var ar5 = \"asaasas //dsdsdsd asdsadsadsad\" //comentario\n"
     + "var ar6 = \"x\" */ + \"asaasas //dsdsdsd asdsadsadsad\"\n"
     + "var ar7 = \"x\" // + \"asaasas //dsdsdsd asdsadsadsad\"\n"
     + "var ar8 = \"asaasas //dsdsdsd asdsadsadsad\" //comentario\n"
     + "var ar9 = \"asaasas //dsdsdsd asdsadsadsad\"";

final String reempl = "$1";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.COMMENTS);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(texto);

final String resultado = matcher.replaceAll(reempl);

System.out.println("TEXTO:\n" + texto);
System.out.println("\nRESULTADO:\n" + resultado);
```

**Resultado**

```
TEXTO:
var ar1 = "asasasas /*dsdsdsd*/ "
var ar2 = "asaasas //dsdsdsd"
var ar3 // = "asaasas //dsdsdsd asdsadsadsad"
/*var ar4*/ = "asasasas /*dsdsdsd*/ dsadasdsda" /*
var ar5 = "asaasas //dsdsdsd asdsadsadsad" //comentario
var ar6 = "x" */ + "asaasas //dsdsdsd asdsadsadsad"
var ar7 = "x" // + "asaasas //dsdsdsd asdsadsadsad"
var ar8 = "asaasas //dsdsdsd asdsadsadsad" //comentario
var ar9 = "asaasas //dsdsdsd asdsadsadsad"

RESULTADO:
var ar1 = "asasasas /*dsdsdsd*/ "
var ar2 = "asaasas //dsdsdsd"
var ar3 
 = "asasasas /*dsdsdsd*/ dsadasdsda"  + "asaasas //dsdsdsd asdsadsadsad"
var ar7 = "x" 
var ar8 = "asaasas //dsdsdsd asdsadsadsad" 
var ar9 = "asaasas //dsdsdsd asdsadsadsad"
```

**Demo**

http://ideone.com/NSGmCL

Comment: Mariano sos el Dios de las expresiones regulares. Por un momento creí que iba a poder desarrollar la regex correcta, pero después de ver tu resultado final me di cuenta que estaba (y estoy) a años luz de distancia. Mil gracias!

Comment: @Genarito muchos caracteres raros, es todo similar... Son 2 o 3 estructuras que se repiten en el regex... Cuesta mucho leerlo al principio, pero te juro que no es tan complicado como se ve

Comment: Hola Mariano, estuve probando tu regex y cuando la testeo me elimina gran parte del código, probé sublime text para ver con que matcheaba y al parecer falta validar un fin de línea que no encuentro: http://subefotos.com/ver/?ba4f8a91042c5c2576570657939e664fo.png

Comment: @Genarito eso es porque solamente estás buscando, en vez de reemplazar. En este caso, se debe reemplazar por `$1`... Acá hay una respuesta que muestra cómo reemplazar: [Regular expression search replace in Sublime Text 2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42257919/5290909)

Comment: Pequeño detalle! Muchas gracias y disculpame las molestias!