# ¿Cómo detectar comentarios con delimitadores /* y */ en regex?

Tags: regex

estoy haciendo una Regex que detecte comentarios, los comentarios deben de empezar con /* y terminar con */ en cualquier parte del texto y puede contener cualquier tipo de carácter incluso puede contener los mismos delimitadores /* y */ pero con la condición de que estén escritos entre comillas "/*" he intentado con esta regex.

```
string regex = @"\/\*(.|\s|(""(\*\/|\/\*)""))*[^""]\*\/";
```

pero esta regex no funciona si tiene mas de 1 comentario por ejemplo:
si el usuario escribe:

```
/\*comentario1\*/
hola esto no es un comentario
/\*comentario2\*/
```

La regex toma como si todo el texto fuera un comentario.
adjunto link a un debugger de regex donde esta hecho este ejemplo: [Enlace del ejemplo](https://regex101.com/r/1nlFzd/1), el problema es el "." que tiene la regex pero es el unico que engloba todos los caracteres

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Expresión regular para eliminación de comentarios de código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56285/expresi%c3%b3n-regular-para-eliminaci%c3%b3n-de-comentarios-de-c%c3%b3digo)

Comment: Ya intentaste reemplazar tu punto por `[a-zA-Z]*` ???

Comment: El problema puntual con el que te encontraste se resuelve cambiando al `(...)*` por `(...)*?`, pero no es lo único a modificar

Comment: @RuslanLópez si pero asi solo consideraría letras de la A a la z y lo que necesito es que considere cualquier caracter

Comment: ¿Incluyendo caracteres como el bloque de símbolos, griego, hiragana, katakana, kanjies y los caracteres no imprimibles?

Comment: @Pollo Resuelve en algo, muchas gracias :) lo unico que le faltaria es cuando el comentario contiene \* o */ dentro del comentario por ejemplo: /* comentario"/**/"sigue el comentario */

Comment: @RuslanLópez no de esos si no por ejemplo caracteres como "!·$%&/()=?¿*^¨_-:;.,[]{}@#~|\ etc..

Comment: Y ya intentaste reemplazando tu punto por `[a-zA-Z!\·\$%&/\(\)=\?¿\*\^¨_-:;.,\[\]\{\}@#~|\\]*` ?? Si nos dijeras la familia de implementación tal vez te podríamos mejorar la expresión regular por ejemplo con un `p{Symbol}` como se usa en Java

Comment: @LuisGarcia por eso dije que "no es lo único" ;-) .. Fijate la publicación que puse en mi primer comentario, que resuelve todo lo que estás preguntando